# Particle as Hair on oval Sphere act wired, goes crazy

Tags: particles, hair

I changed form on a Sphere, added hair and the hair acted crazy.
Tested when Sphere is round, everything works fine. But the moment I change shape from round to oval, hair explodes from the sphere.
What's wrong here?

Add particle like hair to sphere
2. Changed the length and set hard dynamics = true
Start animation and hair will go crazy.

[image: I have changed the Sphere to oval and hair goes crazy.]

Answer (score 1):

You probably made the scale in **object mode**, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  to apply the scale. Use **edit mode** to change the mesh properties

Comment: Thank's, Add all transforms worked.

Comment: @Frank If so, please consider to accept the answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour